# What is the concept behind this 'dual problem'?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Show that the dual of ht epolynomial regression program
$$\min t, -t \leq \sum_{i=0}^{d} c_is^i - f(s) \leq t, \quad \forall s\in S $$
is equivalent to the program
$$\max_{\lambda, \sigma} \frac{1}{2}\big(\sum_{s\in S} \lambda_s f(s) - \sum_{s\in S} \sigma_s f(s)\big) $$
$$ \sum_{s\in S} \lambda_s s^i = \sum_{s\in S} \sigma_s s^i, \quad \forall i\in \{1,\dots,d\} $$
$$ \sum_{s\in S} \lambda_s = \sum_{s\in S} \sigma_s = 1, \lambda\geq 0, \sigma\geq 0$$

And in the solutions it makes the following step that I do not understand:

First we rewrite the nequality constraints of the regression program as:
$$t+\sum_{i=0}^{d} c_is^i \geq f(s), \forall s\in S$$
$$t-\sum_{i=0}^{d} c_is^i \geq -f(s), \forall s\in S$$

**And now comes the part where I lose it:**

Using $\alpha^+, \alpha^- \geq 0$ as the *dual multipliers (?)* for the first and second set of constraints respectively, this yields the dual program:

$$\max \sum_{s\in S} f(s)(\alpha^+ - \alpha^-)$$
$$\sum_{s\in S}(\alpha^+ + \alpha^-) = 1 $$
$$\sum_{s\in S} s^i(\alpha^+ - \alpha^-) = 0, \forall i\in\{0,\dots,d\} $$
$$\alpha^+, \alpha^- \geq 0$$

I do not understand where this step follows from. I've tried to find an explanation for what the dual of a program is and what the dual multipliers are, but I just can't find anything that makes me understand what we've formed here and why it is the dual problem.

Comment: Boyd and Vandenberghe's textbook Convex Optimization has a clear, accessible introduction to the dual problem. The book is free online.

Comment: link to book: https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf (right?)

I've scrolled through chapter 5 and i've seen the langrangian multiplier before, but I don't understand how it applies to my problem?

Comment: Yeah that's it. Chapter 5 explains what the dual problem is and gives a bunch of examples.